# What is the standard xml font in android?

Tags: android, xml, canvas, text, fonts

I have an app in which I use both SurfaceView and TextViews and so on, and when I draw a text on the SurfaceView I'd like it to use the same font as the rest of the xml views, because they look different. Do you know which one should I use(by changing Typeface in paint)?

Answer (score 0):

Android uses Roboto fonts by default. See [the typography documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html).